# Как оформить запрос в ABBYY Lingvo API?

Tags: php, http, api

Хочу поработать с ABBYY Lingvo API. Но не понимаю как с URL сделать запрос. Обрел ключ доступа и не знаю как работать с API дальше.

Вот, в документации дают например:
GET api/v1/WordForms?text={text}&lang={lang}

Описано, что нужно в запросе, и дают пример:
?text=колено&lang=1049

А как он должен выглядеть полностью?

[https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/WordForms?text=колено&lang=1049](https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/WordForms?text=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE&lang=1049)  - не работает

Comment: ну а в консоли и во вкладке нетворк что вам показывает?

Comment: не знаю. сам браузер пишет, что "не отвечает страница"

Comment: из статьи на хабре https://habrahabr.ru/company/abbyy/blog/317102/ "Чтобы начать использовать Lingvo API нужно зарегистрироваться на https://developers.lingvolive.com, используя адрес электронной почты, аккаунт в Facebook, VKontakte, Google, либо войти на сайт с помощью аккаунта Lingvo Live. Затем нужно добавить свое приложение на вкладке «Мои приложения». В бета режиме можно бесплатно зарегистрировать три приложения с лимитом в 50 000 знаков/сутки."

Comment: "Новому приложению автоматически выдаётся стандартный набор словарей и ключ для доступа к API. С этим ключом приложение должно авторизоваться, получить токен для доступа, который нужно прикладывать в заголовок запросов к API. Как это сделать, описано в справке."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выглядит он правильно, не смотря на отвратительную документацию без единого примера, ссылку ты угадал. Но не работает она потому, что кроме самой ссылки на сервер нужно передать Bearer-токен авторизации посредством заголовков!

Bearer-токен можно получить отправив совой API KEY на авторизационную ссылку так-же посредством заголовков!

Вот рабочий пример на PHP получения токена, а потом с помощью него конкретной словарной статьи:

```
//Подготовка заголовков к авторизации
$header = array();
$header[] = 'Content-length: 0';
$header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
$header[] = 'Authorization: Basic {API KEY}';

//Авторизация в ABBYY Lingvo API посредством отправки ключа авторизации
$myCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1.1/authenticate',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header
));
$bearer_token = curl_exec($myCurl);
curl_close($myCurl);

//Модификация заголовков для получения данных
$header[2] = 'Authorization: Bearer '.$bearer_token;

//Получение словарной статьи
$myCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($myCurl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/Minicard?text=plum&srcLang=1033&dstLang=1049',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header
));
$response = curl_exec($myCurl);
curl_close($myCurl);

//Вывод ответа
print_r(json_decode($response));
```